# Python2.6.5 : Is there python equivalent of Java Semaphore tryAcquire

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore, blocking

I am looking for python alternative for Java's tryAcquire Semaphore function. I found out that this function is added in python version 3 and after. I am using python version 2.6.5. Any alternatives for me ? Only thing I have here is semaphore.acquire(blocking=False)
This is my code in Java - (semaphore release is being done in another thread whose code i have not included)

```
if(Sem.tryAcquire(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS))   
   log.info("testCall Semaphore acquired ");
else 
   log.error("Semaphore Timeout occured");
```

Comment: Could `threading.Lock` work? Take a look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html).

Comment: No threading.Lock is also similar to threading.semaphore. Does not provide timeout! I was thinking may be I can use sem.acquire and looping using threading.timer. But timer wakes up in other thread. My main thread will continue executing after I call timer.start and that is the problem with timer !

Answer (score 1):

`Semaphore` is implemented in pure Python - see http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/threading.py , starting at line 236. The `acquire` method is implemented this way:

```
def acquire(self, blocking=True, timeout=None):
    if not blocking and timeout is not None:
        raise ValueError("can't specify timeout for non-blocking acquire")
    rc = False
    endtime = None
    with self._cond:
        while self._value == 0:
            if not blocking:
                break
            if timeout is not None:
                if endtime is None:
                    endtime = _time() + timeout
                else:
                    timeout = endtime - _time()
                    if timeout <= 0:
                        break
            self._cond.wait(timeout)
        else:
            self._value = self._value - 1
            rc = True
    return rc
```

`self._cond` is a [Condition](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#condition-objects) wrapping a [Lock](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock).

You could use `Semaphore`'s technique directly in your code instead of using the class, but it would probably be easier to copy the entire class into your own code. If forward compatibility is an issue, you could even condition it out like so:

```
from threading import *
from sys import version_info

if version_info < (3, 2):
    # Need timeout in Semaphore.acquire,
    # from Python 3.3 threading.py
    class Semaphore:
        ...
```

Whichever way you do this, you will also need the new `Condition` class - according to the docs for `Condition.wait`,

> The return value is `True` unless a given timeout expired, in which case
>   it is `False`.
>
> *Changed in version 3.2*: Previously, the method always returned `None`.

The `Semaphore` timeout code relies on this behavior. The rabbit hole doesn't appear to go any deeper than that, but, your easiest solution might even be to *copy* the entire 3.3 `threading.py`, make any changes it needs to run on 2.x, and add a prominent comment at the top that you're deliberately shadowing the stdlib.

Comment: So, I have put Condition and Semaphore in my own file inside version_info check. However, my code still seems to go to built-in classes when initialize the semaphore and call 'acquire'. It gives me - acquire() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout' .  I am calling acquire from another file where I have declared           from forms.py import Semaphore .... Any idea what more declaration I should provide ?

Comment: @Ivc okay, flow is coming to my code now. I defined the code above! Thanks

Comment: No, the solution isnt working. Semaphore needs Condition which needs Lock. So I copied all three. But still Lock implementation needs thread.allocate_lock so then I tried the second approach - copy entire  threading.py . However, running this file on 2.6 seems to be big task. There is a lot of code, dependent on 3.x python version. Errors will just not go!!